# TTPostController - Keyboard is not appearing

Tags: iphone, three20, uikeyboard

Hi
I am adding a "post comment section in my iPhone APP"
rest all things are working fine but when I tap on "postController textView" a keyboard is suppose to appear from the bottom but it is not appearing However the cursor is displaying and the text that I am passing using *postController.textView.text = @""* is also displaying.

Please suggest the areas to be looked for fixing this bug.

```
   -(void)showCommentView
    {
        TTPostController *postController = [[TTPostController alloc] init];

    // self must implement the  TTPostControllerDelegate protocol
        postController.delegate = self; 
        self.popupViewController = postController;

     // assuming self to be the current UIViewController
        postController.superController = self;
            postController.textView.text=@"temporary text";
        [postController showInView:self.view animated:YES];
        [postController release];
    }
```

above is the code that is giving call to the Three20 PostController

Comment: Does Three20 really require you to set popupViewController and superController for this? Since showInView method is enough for the purpose of display. Maybe that's it?

Comment: @Gurupratap, It is not working even if that line is commented.

Comment: is your self (or the self.view) is a view that is full screen or sub controller/view of a different one?

Comment: @Guy Ephraim it is not a subview, its the full screen.

Comment: @all - the code I posted here id all fine working with the modifications i made to the other code. So We'll consider this code to be correct and there is no bug in this method definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**below is the calling method which is unchanged...**

```
    -(IBAction)postComment:(id)sender
            {
        [UserManager instance]authenticateUserAndProceed:self withSelector:@selector(showCommentView)];
        }
-(void)showCommentView
    {
        TTPostController *postController = [[TTPostController alloc] init];

    // self must implement the  TTPostControllerDelegate protocol
        postController.delegate = self; 
        self.popupViewController = postController;

     // assuming self to be the current UIViewController
        postController.superController = self;
            postController.textView.text=@"temporary text";
        [postController showInView:self.view animated:YES];
        [postController release];
    }
```

**changed method**

```
-(void)authenticateUserAndProceed:(id)parent withSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    theParentViewController = parent;
    self.theFunctionToCall = selector;
    if(userid == nil)
    {
        GetUserInfoViewController *guivc = [[GetUserInfoViewController alloc] init];
        [parent presentModalViewController:guivc  animated:YES];
        guivc.delegate = self;
        [guivc release];
    }


    else {
//////////////////// below line was replaced///////////
//  2.          [theParentViewController performSelector:selector];
// with below code
    UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWith Title........
    [alert show];

        }
    }
```

PROBLEM SUMMARY: 
as soon as the user registered, he was not able to the kyboard for the TTPostController

CHANGE SUMMARY: 
As soon as the user is registered the call to 
    [theParentViewController performSelector:selector];
is not sent directly but the call goes to ann alertview which inter calls it.

EFETCS SUMMARY: 
the user will see a "you are registered successfully" (kind of) alertview.
tapping OK on which, he will be sent to TTPostController. (this time the keyboard is appearing)

I kept the line# 2 in the AlertViewDelegate method.
I was amazed o see it working just by not calling the line 2 directly.

this worked for me.
I welcome any new and better idea to implement the same